# Windows fails to install when system has more than 4 GB of memory installed

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, memory-limit

A) My specs:

1. Intel Core i3
2. MSI H55M-P31 (4 memory slots; dual channel)
3. DDR3 1333 MHz 2 x 2 GB & 2 x 4 GB  (were bought yesterday) and + 2 x 4 GB (borrowed from friend 100% working on other machines)
4. Windows 7 x64

B) I wanted to extend my RAM and ran to an issue. Windows 7 fails at the end of loading. It power offs and reboots. I don't know if it's the motherboard, power, or something else. I've spent 2 days investigating such things and nothing helped.

1. Re-installed Windows from different images
2. Memtest shows no errors
3. Updated BIOS to last one
4. Tried different memory combinations, i.e. 2&4
   4&4 etc, works only 1x2gb, 2x2gb or 1x4gb
5. Tried to change ratios in BIOS
6. Windows and Ubuntu installers from USB/DVD fail if PC has more than 4 GB
   installed. However, it works in safe mode, and shows 8 GB (~7.79 GB used)
7. Even removed CMOS battery from motherboard

C) facts that i'm sure

1. Power block is ok and its power is enough
2. RAM is not bad
3. There should be no reason for the motherboard to be corrupted. It's 3 years old, and was idle at one place

What did I miss? Please give some advice. I appreciate any recommendations and help.

Comment: What are the memory limits of your laptop in the OEM specifications.  More importantly the model of the laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound He specified the motherboard model. The [limit of that board](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/H55M-P31.html#/?div=Basic) is 16GB, and the speed of RAM he is using is supported.

Comment: @Moses he used the phrase power brick that indicates a laptop.  8 and 4 is an odd combination of memory and likely the cause of the problem

Comment: See if you memory is on this list https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.msi.com%2Ffile%2Ftest_report%2FTR10_1976.pdf

Comment: Ramhound its not a laptop

@malakrsnaslava what the list is it ? my are not there,

Comment: I'm sure it's not the case, but is any of the RAM ECC? It's worth making sure it's not ECC...

Comment: Have you tried installing your original working set, then adding one new stick at a time? So basicly, get your system back up with the original ram. Shut down, pull power plug, drain power from board, get rid of static (ground yourself) install ONE new stick, then power up. If it passes post and bios and goes to windows, do the steps again adding the second new stick.

Comment: @Carl B lol, it would be more simpler than write this topic here and w8 answers....

of course i did, if i add more than 4 GB it fails at "end of Windows loading stage"

Comment: the most curioгs question is - why it launches in safe mode ? with 8 gb